# What is _events and what is it used for?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Searching [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-17) I see it is used 12 times and always attached to `this` inside of Backbone.Events.

Is it simply a property of Backbone.Events?  If so why does it have the underscore prefix?

What is it used for?

```
on: function(name, callback, context) {
      if (!(eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) && callback)) return this;
      this._events || (this._events = {});
      var list = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
      list.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
      return this;
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore is meant to indicate that it should be treated as a private property.  `_events` is a map of event callbacks used by Backbone.Events.

Any property or method added to a javascript object is public.  The underscore is a widely used convention to show that the property/method is not to be used outside of the object.

Here is a classic link that explains it a bit:
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: @pure_code: That's why the answer says **"The underscore is meant to indicate [...]"**. Since private properties don't exist in JavaScript, naming conventions are often used to indicate privacy.

Comment: Nothing is really private in javascript, this is why people use the underscore prefix.  You can achieve privacy by using [closures](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).  In this case, you _could_ modify `_events` from outside, but you probably should not.

Comment: `_private` is a local variable, not a property of some object.

Comment: You can look at the [source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) and see how it is used. It is just used as a map of registered events. When you use `on` or `listenTo` the callbacks get added to `_events`. It is an object meant for internal use only, you shouldn't directly access it, hence the `_` :)